# TYPO3 custom aspect and routing not used

Tags: typo3, url-routing, typo3-9.x

I wrote a custom Aspect for better doing better routes in my TYPO3 project. And use it within my **config.yaml** at the end, configuring the URL-generation for my TXPO3-extension.

```
...
  PsoabillingPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Psoabilling
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/banddetail/{bandname}'
        _controller: 'Band::showband'
        _arguments: 
          name: bandname
    defaultController: 'Band::listyear'
    aspects:
      bandname:
        type: BandAndYearMapper
```

But, the URLs are not processed. They stay the same as without the configuration. 
(btw: the additional configuration for EXT:news above my configuration does work as expected!)

Any thoughts?
Thanx
EnzephaloN

Comment: Did you try with a fixed path prefix within `routePath`? This is necessary in order to determine the route to use.

Comment: Hello @Daniel . Ok, the routePath was wrong. But this did not solved my problem - URLs from this kind are not processed.

Comment: Just some wild guesses cause I wrote my first custom aspect yesterday: Have you cleared the core, extbase reflection and frontend caches? Have you tried writing the routePath in one line? Have you tried putting a debug and exit statement within your generate() method to see if its called at all?

Comment: @j4k3 : The custom aspect is not called - thats the problem. I do not seem, why the given YAML does not work. The routePath, controller and arguments are correct, also as type, extension and plugin. But it is not executed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
I was wrong about the mapping of REPLACEMENT: ARGUMENTFIELD...
The URL-argument is tx_psoabilling[band] and not [name]...

Must be:

```
...
  PsoabillingPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Psoabilling
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/banddetail/{bandname}'
        _controller: 'Band::showband'
        _arguments: 
          bandname: band
    defaultController: 'Band::listyear'
    aspects:
      bandname:
        type: BandAndYearMapper
```

But sadly now I got a new problem. The cHash is attached to the url and the link does not work because of a cHash-comparsion-error. But thats another post...